# Cut specific rows within a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to find the best way to download the master CSV file from:
https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.csv and cut row #1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Keep row 3 for the actual headers.

My goal is to schedule a cron job every day to download the file automatically and save it locally on the web server.  I have a plugin that read the .csv file and display as a table (search function, filters, etc) after that.

Thanks

so far I have:

```
** Download the file **

<?php

    $output_filename = "master.csv";

    $host = "https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.csv";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xcontest.org");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result); 


    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);

?>

** Cut the first 2 rows, keep headers, cut rows until data **

function csv_delete_rows($filename=NULL, $startrow=0, $endrow=0, $inner=true) {
$status = 0;

    $updatedcsv = array();
    $count = 0;

    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        $count++;
        if ($startrow > 0 && $endrow > 1) {
            if ($inner) {
                $status = 1;
                if ($count >= $startrow && $count <= $endrow)
                    continue;
                array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
            }
        $count++;
        if ($startrow > 1 && $endrow > 9) {
            if ($inner) {
                $status = 1;
                if ($count >= $startrow && $count <= $endrow)
                    continue;
                array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
            }

        $finalcsvfile = implode("\n", $updatedcsv);
        fclose($fp);
        $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
        fwrite($fp, $finalcsvfile);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return $status;
} else {
    die('File does not exist');
}
```

Comment: You need to open your file for reading, and then use `fgetcsv` in a loop to get the data of the individual rows. And based on whether the loop index (resp. minus one, if you start counting at zero) is one of those you do not want to keep, you either discard the current row data, or write it to a new file using `fputcsv`.

Comment: Hi was this ever achieved... looking at doing this now myself...